# Passing dynamic arguments to a function called by a dynamically added link

Tags: javascript

I am trying to dynamically insert a link into the DOM. The link hyperlinks to another Javascript function that takes in a single argument.

Depending on the variable type of the argument (integer or string), the function either generates an error or behaves as expected.

*Edit: added a CodePen demo [here](https://codepen.io/lightblubhotel/pen/rNVoRaP)*

```
function appendLink(userInput){

    var functionLink = document.createElement("a");
        functionLink.innerHTML = "Call Function";
        functionLink.href = "javascript:func("+ userInput + ")"; //calling function + concatenating dynamic input

    document.body.append(functionLink);
}
```

```
function func(arg){
    alert(arg);
}
```

If `arg` is a string (e.g.: `userInput = 83we0` -- this is the exact argument in my code), I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

However, if `arg` is numerical (e.g.: `userInput = 62121`), then the program behaves as expected, alerting "62121" when the dynamically-appended link is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering

```
func("+ userInput + ")";
```

Numbers work because the produced syntax will be something like

```
func(123)
```

Non-numbers won't, because the produced syntax will be something like

```
func(83we0)
```

Strings require delimiters.

While you could fix this by conditionally adding delimiters and escaping them inside the argument, it would be far better to [avoid inline handlers entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), and use `addEventListener` instead, that way you don't have to worry about silly and tedious escaping issues:

```
functionLink.addEventListener('click', () => func(userInput));
```

Do that instead of assigning `javascript:` to the `href`.